# Rename a GridFS collection & now cannot see files with the list command in mongofiles utility

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

Would any one know how I can view in the mongofiles utility the files in my renamed GridFS collection in MongoDB?

Frist, I insert a number of text files into the fs collection.

When I run:

```
~$ mongofiles -db mydb list
```

I see the names of the files I inserted.

In the mongo shell I successfully ran:

```
>db.fs.files.renameCollection("mycollect.files")
>db.fs.chunks.renameCollection("mycollect.chunks")
```

With the find command in the mongo shell, I see the information about the renamed collections (`mycollect.chunks` & `mycollect.files`).

When I use the mongofiles utility from the commandline, I can NOT bring a list of files using:

```
~$ mongofiles -db mydb -c mycollect.files list
```

Also **does not work**:

```
~$ mongofiles -db mydb -c mycollect.chunks list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, that is a documentation bug. The `-c` parameter has no effect, see MongoDB's Jira issue [SERVER-4931](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4931) and the [`mongofiles` documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/program/mongofiles/#cmdoption--collection):

> `--collection <collection>, -c <collection>`
>
> This option has no use in this context and a future release may remove it.

You can, however, access those collections using the drivers' GridFS implementations, most drivers seem to support this.

--- edit ---

You might want to take a look at [SERVER-1970](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1970) where someone has apparently provided a [pull request](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/pull/347), but it's no longer in the repository!?

Comment: Thank you mnemosyn!  Using MongoVUE, I was able to view & retrieve my files in the renamed GridFS object.  I just wanted a way to verify that I have successfully renamed a GridFS object.